# How to set the focus to the first row first column cell in a rhandsontable in an RShiny app?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, rhandsontable

I need to set focus on the first-row first-column cell of a rhandsontable in an RShiny app. Looking for a solution similar to the solutions discussed in this forum: [Set the focus to a specific datagrid cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129082/set-the-focus-to-a-specific-datagrid-cell), [QML: Set focus TextInput in a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127196/qml-set-focus-textinput-in-a-table-cell), [how to focus a table cell using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858611/how-to-focus-a-table-cell-using-javascript), [want to put the focus and edit the first cell of my dynamic table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70662945/want-to-put-the-focus-and-edit-the-first-cell-of-my-dynamic-table?rq=1), etc. I need help with the renderer function to accomplish this.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame(matrix(data = '', nrow = 5, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(seq(1:5),c("Barcode"))))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Scan Sample Barcode"),
  mainPanel(
    rHandsontableOutput("scanBarcode")
  )
  
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scanBarcode <- renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(DF) %>%
                                              hot_cols(renderer = "function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) 
                                                {Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
                                                if (col == 0 & row == 0 ) {td.focus();}")
                                           )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You'd probably get more help if you provide a minimal code to build on.

Comment: I added the code as advised. I would like to add JavaScript as a renderer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the blunder. I updated the code as advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about his:

```r
library(htmlwidgets)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$scanBarcode <- renderRHandsontable(
    rhandsontable(DF) %>% 
    onRender("function(el, x) { 
                 let hot = this.hot;
                 hot.selectCell(0, 0); 
                 hot.getActiveEditor().beginEditing();
             }")  
  )
}
```

You use the [handsontable API](https://handsontable.com/docs/javascript-data-grid/api/) to select the cell (*N.B.* indices are zero based in JS) and then invoke the cell editor.

You place this JS code in the `onRender` function where you have a reference of the handsontable object being created.

[image: Animated screenshot showing a table where the first cell is selected and the editor is invoked on loading]

Comment: fantastic! You made it look so simple. This solution will be useful to many users like me.